# How to Import Python methods in other files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a custom libraries which have following folder structure:

```
DS
 -lib
   -init__.py
   -db.py
   -dispatch.py
   -links.py
```

Now I want to consume files under `lib` in the following folder structure:

```
apps
- framework
  -- test.py
```

When I do `from DS.lib.dispatch import *` in `test.py` it gives error:

> ```
> from lib.db import Links ImportError: No module named 'lib'
> ```

**Update**

`dispatch.py`

```
from lib.db import Links
from lib.links import Link
import numpy as np
from urllib.parse import urlparse


class Dispatch:
    """
        This will pull an individual unprocessed link and pass to dispatcher
    """
    _idle_link = None
    ...
```

Comment: make `__init__.py`  in DS directory and rename `init__.py` to `__init__.py`

Comment: That was a `typo` while pasting..I created `__init__.py` in  `DS` folder but still same error when I do `from DS.lib.dispatch import *` @RaminNietzsche

Comment: @IljaEverilä I added init file as the other commentor suggested, now when I do `from DS.lib import *` and call `d = Dispatch()` it says: `NameError: name 'Dispatch' is not defined`

Comment: At this point I'd say you have to provide the actual module sources. Clearly `DS.lib` does not contain or import `Dispatch`.

Comment: And does the `__init__.py` under `DS.lib` import `Dispatch` from `dispatch.py`?

Comment: did not get you. Initially I was running `test.py` under `DS`.. I am now trying to isolate it and added init file on suggestion of other poster but it did not work either.

Comment: In a previous comment you said you did `from DS.lib import *`, which imports all names from under **DS.lib**, not for example **DS.lib.dispatch**. If DS.lib does not explicitly itself import `Dispatch` first from the module `dispatch`, that star import will not introduce the name. In other words you have to import it from `.dispatch` first in `DS/lib/__init__.py`.

Answer (score 1):

There is more to this topic than I can explain here, but in the simple case of python packages and modules on the file system, it works roughly as follows. Given the following files:

## Modules

A module is a simple `.py` file. These files can be located anywhere on the file system, and do not have to be in a package. A module usually contains class and function declarations. Any code outside of a function/class definition is executed when the module is run/imported.

**/someplace/foo.py**

```
def func():
    print "I am foo.func"

print "I run at module import"
```

## Packages

A package is a directory containing an `__init__.py`. A package can also be located anywhere in the filesystem.  The `__init__.py` module is executed when the package is imported and the contents of this module becomes the contents of the package.

**/anotherplace/bar/__init__.py**

```
def func():
    print "I am bar.func"

print "I run at package import"
```

A package contains modules or other child packages. Child modules are not automatically imported.

**/anotherplace/bar/child.py**

```
def func():
    print "I am bar.baz.func"

print "I run at module import"
```

## Imports

Both modules and packages can be imported from other modules.

When python sees an `import` statement, it searches certain directories for the code.  These directories are the module search path. The search path is made up of:

- the current working directory
- the PYTHONPATH environment variable
- system defaults

You can inspect the current module search path at runtime:

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

You will note that in the examples above, I have put `foo` in `/someplace/` and `bar` in `/anotherplace/`.

If I were to run the python interpreter in `/someplace/` then `import foo` would succeed (because it's found at the current working directory). However `import bar` would fail, because `/anotherplace/` is not on the search path.

For both imports to work, both source folders must be on the search path. Note that the correct source folder for a package is the directory above the one with `__init__.py`. In this case, it should be:

- `/someplace/`
- `/anotherplace/`